# Which is the best method (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) to use for each action while managing users?

Tags: ajax, post, get, put

I have developed a web page using html, php, javascript (with query and ajax) and mysql. In this page, I have a login system and some forms to manage users (change password, register, search, edit and delete). For each one of these actions I have used ajax (with POST method) to avoid redirection. Everything works fine but I want to use the most appropriate method in each case.
In every case I have a form with some inputs and a button in it to submit the data (I call a function in the onclick event). Then, inside these functions, I use ajax to make a request using POST and pass some data to a php file, that select, insert, update or delete the data from the database.

Regarding the definitions of each method I have thought that the best option would be POST for register, PUT for change password and edit user, GET for search (and perhaps login) and DELETE for delete a user. However, I have read that for login is better to use POST because if you use GET you pass the data in the URL (although I'm using ajax to avoid redirection, so I think the URL would be the same). I have also read that some browsers don't support PUT nor DELETE, so it would be better not to use them. Furthermore, I think that ajax doesn't allow to pass data in delete method.

I have seen that many people tend to use POST, but I don't know if it's a good practice or it's something done by default.

What is the best/right/most appropriate option for each action?

Edit: Some more info: Search, register, edit an delete features are only available for the admin role. The rest of the users do login and can change their password.

When the adminastrator does a search (a search of the registered users, using some field value for that, i.e. users with name = "Juan") a table is displayed, and then he can click on edit or delete (these buttons are displayed for each one of the results) and a window or alert is prompted, but the url is always the same and it is not refreshed. I have a more or less static page in which the header, footer and menu are fixed and the only thing that changes is the content. That is one of the reasons why I'm using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is basically how it is displayed. In this case, I don't believe you need delete or put. You should be fine with just using post for everything except the search. By definition, post variables will not show up in the address bar. You don't want people to send links to access there account I'm sure, making post the best for those as the variables remain hidden to the user, but easily accessible through a request method or whatever you like to use on your end. In a search, get would most likely be the best. If somebody wanted to share a result set from a search with their friends, they could easily access the url and send it because the search input would simply be in the address bar at the top of the page. If I didn't answer this question correctly, can you please send a code sample? I hope this helps!

I am not sure that I completely understand what the question you are asking is. I believe what you are asking is, "Why isn't the url changing when the form is submitted?" Tell me if this is correct. If that is the question you are asking, I would like to remind you to make sure your method is GET. Tell me and I will edit the answer if that was not the question you were intending to ask.

Comment: Thanks. The idea is that the URL never changes and that's why I was using POST. I have added some info explaining it. This is part of a student project, so I'm concerned about using this in the rigth way. Perhaps (just as example), I should use PUT, but I could use POST arguing that it's a best option for compatibility reasons.